# Grouping elements with the same ID and finding the maximum value as well as its location

Tags: arrays, matlab, grouping, vectorization

I have two vectors of length 16. The first one, `r`, for example is:

```
r = [1;3;5;7;1;3;6;7;9;11;13;16;9;11;13;16];
```

`r` contains a list of IDs.  I want to collect the indices of the duplicate IDs in `r` so that each group is a list of indices for one ID.  I would then use these indices to access a second vector `a` and find the maximum value incident on the indices for each group.

Therefore, I would like to produce an output vector using `r` and `a` such that:

```
max(a(1),a(5)), max(a(2),a(6)), a(3), a(7), max(a(4),a(8)), max(a(9),a(13)), max(a(10),a(14)), max(a(11),a(15)), max(a(12),a(16))
```

I also want to keep the indices of the maximum values.  How can I efficiently implement this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to assign each unique number in `r` a unique ID.  You can then bin all of the numbers that share the same ID with an [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) call where the key is the unique ID and the value is the actual value of `a` for the corresponding position of the key in this unique ID array.  Once you collect all of these values, use `accumarray` so that you can use these values for each unique value in `r` to reference into `a` and select out the maximum element:

```
%// Define r and a
r = [1;3;5;7;1;3;6;7;9;11;13;16;9;11;13;16];
a = [...];

%// Relevant code
[~,~,id] = unique(r, 'stable');
out = accumarray(id(:), a(:), [], @max);
```

The `'stable'` flag in `unique` is important because we want to assign unique IDs in order of occurrence.  Not doing this will **sort** the values in `r` first before assigning IDs and that's not what we want.

Here's a quick example.  Let me set up your problem with generating a random 16 element array stored in `a` which you are trying to ultimately index.  We'll also set up `r`:

```
rng(123);
a = rand(16,1);
r = [1;3;5;7;1;3;6;7;9;11;13;16;9;11;13;16];
```

This is what `a` looks like:

```
>> a

a =

    0.6965
    0.2861
    0.2269
    0.5513
    0.7195
    0.4231
    0.9808
    0.6848
    0.4809
    0.3921
    0.3432
    0.7290
    0.4386
    0.0597
    0.3980
    0.7380
```

After running through the code, we get this:

```
out =

    0.7195
    0.4231
    0.2269
    0.6848
    0.9808
    0.4809
    0.3921
    0.3980
    0.7380
```

You can verify for yourself that this gives the right result.  Specifically, the first element is the maximum of `a(1)` and `a(5)` which is 0.6965 and 0.7195 respectively, and the maximum is 0.7195.  Similarly, the second element is the maximum `a(2)` and `a(6)`, which is 0.2861 and 0.4231, and the maximum is 0.4231 and so on.

---

If it is your desire to also remember what the indices were used to select out the maximum element, this will be slightly more complicated.  What you need to do is call `accumarray` once again, but the values won't be those of `a` but the actual index values instead.  You'd use the second output of `max` to get the actual location of the value chosen.  However, with the nature of `max`, we can't just grab the second element of `max` without explicitly calling the two-output version of `max` (I really wish there was another way around this... Python has a function in NumPy called `numpy.argmax`) and this can't be properly encapsulated in an anonymous function (i.e. `@(x) ...`), so you're going to need to create a custom function to do that.

Create a new function called `maxmod` and save it to a file called `maxmod.m`.  You'd put this inside the function:

```
function p = maxmod(vals, ind)
    [~,ii] = max(vals(ind));
    p = ind(ii);
```

This takes in an array and a range of indices to access the array, called `vals`.  We'd then find the maximum of these selected results, then return which index gave us the maximum.

After, you'd call `accumarray` like so:

```
%// Define r and a
r = [1;3;5;7;1;3;6;7;9;11;13;16;9;11;13;16];
a = [...];

%// Relevant code
[~,~,id] = unique(r, 'stable');
out = accumarray(id(:), (1:numel(r)).', [], @(x) maxmod(a,x));
```

This is now what I get:

```
>> out

out =

     5
     6
     3
     8
     7
     9
    10
    15
    16
```

If you look at each value, this reflects which location of `a` we chose that corresponds to the maximum of each group.

Comment: Why not `out = accumarray(id(:), a(:), [], @max)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo - hah! Yes! Certainly easier to read.  I originally had an `accumarray` call to group the indices then `cellfun` to apply the max to each group... then I realized I could get rid of the `cellfun`.... but then I forgot to remove the fact that we don't need to use the indices anymore.  Just use `a` directly.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! this works. Could you also explain how to keep the indices of the chosen elements in taking the maximum along with those we don't take maximum on. In your example, I need to keep: 5, 6, 3, ...

Comment: @Elnaz yup... you need to make another `accumarray` call.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Elnaz - have a look.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you. Can we do this without a function? What I want to do actually is to switch the elements of a third vector using the winning indices: image_of_b = b; b(unique(r)) = image_of_b(winning_indices).

Comment: @Elnaz - Why are you opposed to creating an auxiliary function? If desired, you can make this a local function inside your function script file.

Comment: @rayryeng Just for the speed and complexity considerations. Because, I'll be visiting the above line so many times and wanted to save time. But thank you for your answer. Also, in image_of_b = b; b(unique(r)) = image_of_b(winning_indices), I should be using the stable option if I want to use your code above? Am I right?

Comment: yes, `stable` option is what you need.  Also, the auxiliary function has very minimal overhead.  `unique` and `accumarray` are very very fast... you should be able to call this code many times and it should be very efficient.  BTW, thank you for the accept :)

Comment: @rayryeng No, Thank you for your help!